# How to create and return a pointer to an array of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working on a game in C++ using SDL, and I would like to have a master list of entities to use throughout the game. So that I don't want to have to pass around tons of copies of this array, I would like to be able to give functions a pointer to the array of pointers to Entities. The entity class has a wide variety of methods and properties within, so how would I give a pointer for this array that a function could use to iterate over the list of pointers without necessarily knowing the number of entities within?

Comment: Instance manager pattern.

Comment: Why a pointer to an array? Just pass a reference to an `std::vector`.

Comment: Because, as I stated in the question, the Entity class has a host of attributes, methods, and will usually end up being a child class.

Comment: And? What is the relevance of that?

Comment: Did you try googleing "array pointer" ?

Comment: Can pointers be contained in vectors? How would one write the creation of a pointer to a vector of pointers? Most of my experience is in Java, so the syntax for pointers still feels a little alien to me

Comment: And yes, Arthur, I've been researching for a bit now, but nothing quite fits this situation. The only thing i have found is about structures of simple data types, and nothing about a pointer to an array of pointers to big gnarly objects.

Comment: OK, first you ask for an array of objects. I suggest to use a vector instead, and now you are talking about vectors of pointers. An array of X objects maps to a vector of X objects, not a vector of pointers to X. And yes, vectors can store pointers, but it isn't clear that you need that, given that you were asking for an array of objects.

Comment: Read the origional question, Juan. I said array of pointers to objects. "...to give functions a pointer to the array of pointers to Entities." I do understand the difference between pointers and objects, what I do not understand is the difference between vectors and arrays.

Comment: Read the title to your question. And the original question, before your edit.

Comment: Damnitt. I apologize, I do seem to have misspoke in the title. As I said, this is a bit mind-numbing to me at this time of night, and I'm having trouble keeping it all strait. Regardless, you did point me in the right direction with vectors, they seem to be what I want to use. If I could bother with one last thing, though, how do i write the definition of a function that returns a pointer to a vector of class T? Am i correct in assuming, using namespace std, "vector<T>* myfuntion(){}"?

Comment: C++ doesn't always *have* to be over complicated. You can just return a vector from a function by value. So, `std::vector<T> myFunction();`. It is extremely likely that this will involve an extra copy, if that worries you.

Comment: It really does :/ would `std::vector<T>* myFunction();` work as I am assuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to expand on claptrap's answer, this would be a list of pointers to Entitys

```
typedef std::vector<Entity*> EntityList;

EntityList masterEntityList;

void foo1( EntityList& myEntities ) {}
void foo2( EntityList& myEntities ) {}

int main()
{
   masterEntityList.push_back(new Entity);
   foo1(masterEntityList);

}
```

note that passing by reference such as is happening here, is like passing by pointers in that the list is not copied. you are always referencing the same list.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need! You, sir, are a gamesaver :)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::vector<Entity> entities;


void foo1( entities& myEntities ) {}
void foo2( entities& myEntities ) {}
```

have a master vector of entities, pass it by reference to the functions
avoids the copying of the vector.